# как вывести данные из запроса в браузер?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Нужно из SQL-запроса INNER JOIN  в phpmyadmin вывести данные(результат) из 2-х таблиц в браузер

```
 SELECT * FROM `descriptions` INNER JOIN movie USING (description_id)
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: На будущее, база данных называется mysql. А phpmyadmin - это просто программа для работы с этой БД

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы вывести данные, надо сначала их получить в массив, а потом вывести в том виде, который требуется в конкретном случае.

Чтобы получить данные в массив, необходимо:

1. Соединиться с БД. Код соединения можно взять [здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#oop) и сохранить в файл `mysqli.php`.
2. Выполнить запрос. В случае, если в запросе не используются переменные, это делается функцией `query()`.
3. Получить результаты запроса в массив. это делает функция fetch_all(). Чтобы получить доступ к элементам массива по именам полей, используется параметр MYSQLI_ASSOC

То есть код будет примерно таким

```
<?php
require 'mysqli.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `descriptions` INNER JOIN movie USING (description_id)";
$data = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Вывод же зависит от требуемого формата. Например, если нам нужен JSON, то

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Если надо вывести в HTML, то пишем этот HTML а отдельном РНР файле, и инклюдим его,

```
include 'movies.php';
```

Внутри HTML выводим так:

```
<div>
    <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
        <div><?= $row['title'] ?></div>
        <div><?= $row['descroption'] ?></div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я не знаю, что ты делаешь не так

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rx6UNJ4H  https://wampi.ru/image/6oKxfGO

Comment: Это ОЧЕНЬ странная ошибка. К РНР не имеет отношения. У тебя что-то с компом. Попробуй перезагрузиться. Проверить на вирусы. Вот ответ про эту ошибку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317974/mysql-php-error2002-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-a

Comment: У меня нет тех файлов, путь по которым там указан.

Comment: Дело вообще не в файлах. В в том что у тебя система больна